# Can I set a variable amount of memory for SLURM jobs?

Tags: pytorch, slurm

I am on a school server, where we have a login node, and several GPU nodes that can be accessed with SLURM. Specifically, I am running several jobs on a machine with 512 GB RAM, 64 CPUS, and 8 GPUs.

I want to train a large deep-learning model with a ton of text. After some trial and error, it seems I need 100 GB of RAM to load all the text data (12 GB batch file on disk) successfully, before training starts. However, while training, it only uses about 30 GB of RAM. I want to run several versions of this model, so I can only do up to 5 before running out of RAM to allocate.

Is there a way to have SLURM use a variable amount of RAM? I don't want to hog up too many resources unnecessarily. This are the SBATCH directives I am currently using:

```
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=20G
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=5
#SBATCH --nodelist=gpu-large
#SBATCH --gpus=1
```

I currently have 3 jobs running, and this is what I see from `free`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          503Gi        94Gi       246Gi       1.6Gi       161Gi       403Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi        96Mi       3.9Gi
```

So my jobs indeed only are using 30 GB each. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: the following is from memory, I have no access to a slurm cluster ATM to check that.

You should be able to update the memory requirement of the job after it started. AFAIR, as a simple user (as opposed to a slurm admin or root), you can only lower the limits, not increase them (to prevent highjacking priority or ressources). Say, if your job has a memory-intensive `step0` followed by a less intensive `step1`, you could try something like the following:

```sh
# Memory intensive part
step0
# Lower ressource reservation
scontrol update JobId=$SLURM_JOBID MinMemoryCPU=6G
# Less intensive step
step1
```

Some general info there: https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html

Comment: Appreciate the reply! Finally got around to testing this. However, I think this is the opposite of what I want?  I wanted to free up memory, and I think updating `MinMemoryCPU` doesn't do that (since memory is allocated based on the max memory right?) I suppose we want to change `MaxMemPerCPU` instead, but I get `Update of this parameter is not supported`.

Comment: No, minmemory ils what you need, as a user. You need the batch system to allocate you at least the minmemory you request. Maxmemory is set by the admin for the partition.